# Wav2Vec2ForCTC were not initialized from the mode, pass 'sampling_rate' argument

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, huggingface-transformers

my code kind of working (it is listening and capturing my voice) but is warning me!! I am keeping having this issue with the code as:

```
1)
UserWarning: positional arguments and argument "destination" are deprecated. nn.Module.state_dict will not accept them in the future. Refer to https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.state_dict for details.
warnings.warn(
Some weights of Wav2Vec2ForCTC were not initialized from the model checkpoint at facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h and are newly initialized: ['wav2vec2.masked_spec_embed']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
```

Listening Now..

```
2)
It is strongly recommended to pass the ``sampling_rate`` argument to this function. Failing to do so can result in silent errors that might be hard to debug.
```

---

```
import torch
import speech_recognition as sr
import io
from pydub import AudioSegment
from transformers import Wav2Vec2ForCTC, Wav2Vec2Processor

tokenizer = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h")
model = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h")
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

while True:
    audio = recognizer.listen(source)
    data = io.BytesIO(audio.get_wav_data())
    clip = AudioSegment.from_file(data)
    tensor = torch.FloatTensor(clip.get_array_of_samples())

    inputs = tokenizer(tensor, sample_rate=16000, return_tensors="pt", padding="longest").input_values
    logits = model(inputs).logits
    tokens = torch.argmax(logits, dim=-1)
    text = tokenizer.batch_decode(tokens)

    print(str(text).lower())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import soundfile as sf
import torch       
ds, samplerate = sf.read(audio_file)
input_values = speech_tokenizer(ds  , return_tensors="pt", sampling_rate = samplerate, padding="longest"  )
```

pass sampling_rate to speechtokenizer to solve sampling_rate warning
and make sure your "sampling_rate": 16000